# Retrieve the Data in Tree structure in php

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony-2.1

Currently i am working on creating apis in symfony2.2 framework.

I have to retrieve a bunch of questions and answers from the database.

```
                               Q1
                              /  \
                             A1   A2
                            /       \
                           Q2        Q3
                          / | \     / | | \
                         A3 A4 A5  A6 A7 A8 A9 
                        /   |
                       Q4   Q2  ...
```

My DB structure is as follows:

```
Question: (questionId,questionText)
AnswerOption: (id,questionId,option,nextQuestionId)
```

Here in the above diagram there is one root question which has 2 choices A1 and A2.

On select of A1 the user must be redirected to Q2 and so on and so forth.

NOTE : The user may not answer all the questions.

Now I need to find the Best way to:

1: Retrieve the data From the database.

2: Format the Questions in Json file.

Comment: You probably need to use the nested set model in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First you take the key from database for a1, and a2 from where it stored, now you retrive data from different table based upon your selection,just match id's (selected from A1 and A2) and retrive  datas  which matchs your selection ID and do so on so forth.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST) {
        $nextQues = "SELECT * from Question WHERE id = '" . $_POST['next_ques_id'] . "'";
        $nxtAnswers = "SELECT * from AnswerOption WHERE questionId = '" . $_POST['next_ques_id'] . "'";
    }
?>

// in view, loop through $nxtAnswers and assign $nxtAnswers['nextQuestionId'] to input
<?php foreach ($nxtAnswers as $ans): ?>
    <input type="radio" name="next_ques_id" value="<?=$nxtAnswers['nextQuestionId']?>"><?=$ans['option']?></input>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this kind of tree structure for main/sub heading in documents.

You can use recursive function to retrieve next question.You can manage how many question going to retrieve inside of recursion function.

**Suggestion:**

As your table structure, you are using two tables. You can do it using one table for questions and can use option table for answers. Because next question also a another question. That means there is an unary one to one relationship with questions.

```
Tables:
question : (id,optionId,questionText, nextQuestionId)
 pk - id
 foreign key - optionId

option: (id, optionText, questionId)
 foreign key - questionId
 PK - id
```

I think this will be helpful for you.

This post also helpful for you.

[Understanding Recursion in PHP/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399516/understanding-recursion-in-php-mysql)

Comment: Yes. Use another table to store options. like this. 
option: (id, optionText, questionId)